# how to add break points to all the methods in the controller in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I need to add permissions for all functions in all the controllers in my code. So i need to add break points at all the functions to check which ones are called during every click made while using my application. Is there any short cut.

Comment: manually setting the breakpoints is not an option?

Comment: No, here is no shortcut...

Comment: there are more than 100 method used :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set breakpoints to all methods in a class at once in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625732/can-i-set-breakpoints-to-all-methods-in-a-class-at-once-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Check out an extension called [Breakpoint Generator.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b4aaf8aa-58ab-40a1-b45c-feb3efc94e1e)